# A problem with getting a coefficient

Tags: symbolic, arithmetic

I try

```
Coefficient[E^(I a (t - b)), E^(I a t)]
```

and expect the output

```
E^(-I a b)
```

but in fact I get `0`.

What should be corrected in my code? I cannot solve this problem for a week.

Comment: Since the documentation on `Coefficient[]` speaks of polynomials _only_, why do you expect anything sensible?

Comment: @IgorRivin So is it possible to do what I want?

Comment: I am sure it is *possible*, but it may be a little painful, the question is: what is it you are really trying to do?

Comment: I need to collect the coefficients of exponents with particular powers e.g. E^(I a t), E^(I b t) and so on. Now I see that it is not a Coefficient[] but any other method. Somehow I did not pay attention that Coefficient[] processes only polynomials.

Comment: The question is whether your terms are textually explicit (if yes, it is not too hard to do with patterns, if not, it becomes a little iffy).

Comment: Not to mention that you could multiply any expression by `E^(a t) E(-a t)`. That's why it makes sense for polynomials only.

Comment: Anyway thank you for help. I think I need to reconsider something in my program when working with exponents. The Coefficient[] does not fit to my problem because it is not a polynomial.

Comment: Possibly you can get the sort of behavior you want by using `TrigExpand[ExpToTrig[expression]]` and the trying to extract the coefficients of `Cos[a*t]` and `Sin[a*t]`. Another approach would be to recast as an explicit polynomial, by converting `Exp[I*a*t]` to a "variable" `eiat` and likewise for `Exp[I*a*b]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Coefficient[E^(I a (t - b)) // ExpandAll, E^(I a t)]

(* Exp[-I a b] *)
```

Comment: You can delete your comment, just click on the "X" sign next to the time. I'll delete mine, I can't delete yours.